# download PDF file from url and reuse the downloaded file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app where i have several pdf urls to get from the internet. when the user clicks on a cell named as the pdf file, this pdf should open in a `UIWebView` and get stored on the phone so the next time the user clicks on the row, the file loads from the app not from the internet.

I'VE BEEN SEARCHING FOR WEEKS and i couldn't find any solution, can anyone help me please ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can do this:

```
// Get the PDF Data from the url in a NSData Object
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/info.pdf"]];


// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: found this one and tried it did not work out .. error "The requested URL was not found on this server." although the url is fine.

Comment: Then please check with your server team as I've been using this and it works all fine for me.

Comment: i am able to load the url from the server without saving it .. but when i use this it won't work .. also i've tried it with the url you used still not working

Comment: So you are saying when you replace your PDF url here in first line, pdfData is nil?

Comment: not at all .. i am receiving data but the request is failing with error when i am loading the url from the path ..

Comment: I see. Could you please let me know the value for `filePath ` in your case and that check in that file path if your PDF exists post `writeToFile:` call.

Comment: /Users/OBSoft/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68107367-E868-4707-9677-A6FB263B2C6D/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BE594BA4-6383-4BFB-A035-5DD1CBE59306/Documents/http:/i3lan.ob-soft.com/web/uploads/images/Gavin---Pressure-transmitter--GPT200-.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90116/discussion-between-abhinav-and-user3783005).

Comment: po [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES] returns nil

Answer (score 1):

i finally did solve it by finding some answers and merging them ..

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0],@"fileName.pdf"]; 
NSMutableArray *directory = [[fullPath componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] mutableCopy]; 
[directory removeObjectAtIndex:[directory count]-1]; 
NSError *error = [[NSError alloc]init]; 
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[directory componentsJoinedByString:@"/"]]){ 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:[directory componentsJoinedByString:@"/"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; 
} 
[data writeToFile:fullPath atomically:NO];
```